# extending a tax class into an existing company extension

Tags: magento, tax

I have extended Magento core files before but in this case wish to extend a class

```
//app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php
i.e. Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation
```

into an existing component my company had:

```
//app/code/local/Mycompany/Model/Companytaxrate.php
i.e. Mycompany_Companytaxrate_Model_Companytaxrate
```

The module `Companytaxrate` is already in place as is this file.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation` from your new model:

```
class Mycompany_Companytaxrate_Model_Companytaxrate extends Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation
{
}
```

From there, you'd rewrite the model inside your /etc/config.xml file:

```
<global>
  <models>
    <tax>
      <rewrite>
        <calculation>Mycompany_Companytaxrate_Model_Companytaxrate</calculation>
      </rewrite>
    </tax>
  </models>
</global>
```